# How to compare only first three characters and remove matching elements?

Tags: java, string-comparison

I need to **compare** only the **first three characters** from elements of the given `ArrayList` with a given text and remove days that match.

For example, if the given text is `"MON"`, then it should compare with the elements of `daysList` and remove `"MONDAY"`.

What I tried is

```
private String[] daysList = { "MONDAY", "TUESDAY", "WEDNESDAY",
    "THURSDAY", "FRIDAY", "SATURDAY", "SUNDAY" };

// It only works if using "MONDAY" instead
private givenString = "MON";

List<String> asSet = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(daysList));

// It fails here
asSet.remove(givenString);

String[] newDayList = asSet.toArray(new String[]{});
```

Comment: `String upToThreeCharacters = s.substring(0, Math.min(s.length(), 3));`
use this for taking `n` char. and you can check with your arraylist values using `equalsIgnoreCase()`

Comment: What's the significance of the name `asSet`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Set.removeIf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) and [`String.startsWith()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith-java.lang.String-):

```
asSet.removeIf(s -> s.startsWith(givenString));
```

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

The problem is that you use `asSet.remove(givenString);`. This method searches for exactly that element. If you give `"MON"` then only elements with content `"MON"` will be removed.

### Solutions

A manual approach would be like

```
// Iterate all elements
Iterator<String> elements = aSet.iterator();
while (elements.hasNext()) {
    String element = elements.next();

    // Compare first three characters
    boolean doMatch = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        char first = givenString.charAt(i);
        char second = element.charAt(i);

        if (first != second) {
            doMatch = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Remove if matches
    if (doMatch) {
        // Remove element at current position
        elements.remove();
    }
}
```

However there is no need to reinvent the wheel. You may just use the `String#startsWith` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith-java.lang.String-)) method:

```
Iterator<String> elements = aSet.iterator();
while (elements.hasNext()) {
    String element = elements.next();

    if (element.startsWith(givenString)) {
        elements.remove();
    }
}
```

And if you have Java 8 you can use `Collection#removeIf` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-)) and everything breaks down to

```
aSet.removeIf(element -> element.startsWith(givenString));
```

Note that an `ArrayList` is **not** a `Set`, since you called it *aSet*. A `List` is different to a `Set`, a set has no order (at least the regular definition) and can't contain duplicates.